# How can I trigger SwiftUI animation only when the flag is true?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I want to trigger animation only when the trigger is true, not always when it changes.

I don't see any source for doing that, is it achievable?

```
Label("Test", systemImage: "magnifyingglass")
  .keyframeAnimator(
    initialValue: AnimationValues(),
    trigger: animationIsActive
  ) { content, frame in
    content
      .scaleEffect(frame.scale)
  } keyframes: { _ in
    KeyframeTrack(\.scale) {
      LinearKeyframe(0.5, duration: 0.1)
      LinearKeyframe(1.5, duration: 0.1)
      LinearKeyframe(1.0, duration: 0.1)
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean, the animation should only happen when a boolean trigger changes from false to true, but not when it changes from true to false?  If so, then you can apply the scaling conditionally in the content view builder closure.

Like this:

```swift
Label("Test", systemImage: "magnifyingglass")
    .keyframeAnimator(
        initialValue: AnimationValues(),
        trigger: animationIsActive
    ) { content, frame in
            content
                .scaleEffect(animationIsActive ? frame.scale : 1) // <- HERE
    } keyframes: { _ in
        KeyframeTrack(\.scale) {
            LinearKeyframe(0.5, duration: 0.1)
            LinearKeyframe(1.5, duration: 0.1)
            LinearKeyframe(1.0, duration: 0.1)
        }
    }
```

Alternatively, if you mean it should animate continuously if the flag is true, but not animate at all when the flag is false, then you just need to use `keyframeAnimator(initialValue:repeating:content:keyframes:)` instead and apply the scaling conditionally in the same way:

```swift
Label("Test", systemImage: "magnifyingglass")
    .keyframeAnimator(
        initialValue: AnimationValues(),
        repeating: true // <- HERE
    ) { content, frame in
            content
                .scaleEffect(animationIsActive ? frame.scale : 1)
    } keyframes: { _ in
        KeyframeTrack(\.scale) {
            LinearKeyframe(0.5, duration: 0.1)
            LinearKeyframe(1.5, duration: 0.1)
            LinearKeyframe(1.0, duration: 0.1)
        }
    }
```